# ng-value dont work on select with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I use this controller to make Years value in ng-options select:

```
    $http.post('http://www.lavorirapidi.it/app/include/profilo.asp?username='+username+'&id='+user_id)
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.profilo = data;
        $scope.nome = username;
        })
    .error(function(){alert("Errore di comunicazione!")});

$scope.totalyears = 100;
$scope.years = [];
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    for (var i = currentYear; i > currentYear - $scope.totalyears; i--) {
    $scope.years.push(i - 1);
    }
```

and this is the html:

```
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="profilo.anno" ng-options="o for o in years" ng-value="profilo.anno">
          <option value="YYYY">YYYY</option>
        </select>
```

But I notice that if the ng-value exist (for example is 1999), is not set on the select menu!

Where is the problem?!

EDIT

I think my problem is in the controller!

Comment: Use `ng-selected` instead of `ng-value`

Comment: Could you reproduce in a plunker ? I don't have this issue when i test it http://plnkr.co/edit/rOAiUSz0OB8wao56q31L?p=preview If you want it to auto-set you just need to assign this value to "profilo.anno"

Comment: the problem is that profilo.anno is set by $http call!

Answer (score 0):

try this : [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mRJDuKqziqfVnE3Ojtmz?p=preview)

Controller code:

```
 $scope.totalyears = 100;
    $scope.profilo = {anno:2013};
    $scope.years = [];
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        for (var i = currentYear; i > currentYear - $scope.totalyears; i--) {
        $scope.years.push(i - 1);

    }
```

Comment: i think my problem is in the controller

Comment: any idea?! My problem is that profilo.anno is taken from $http call

Comment: oh okay. Define  $scope.profilo; in your controller and check it.

Comment: but I just set it, look the code: $scope.profilo = data; where data is the json result of $http call